# "More of ... than"

Tags: grammar

> In the early 1950’s, historians who studied preindustrial Europe (which we may define here as Europe in the period from roughly 1300 to 1800) began, for the first time in large numbers, to investigate **more of the** preindustrial European population **than** the 2 or 3 percent who comprised the political and social elite：the kings，generals, judges, nobles, bishops, and local magnates who had hitherto usually filled history books.

In the sentence above, what I do not understand is the part "to investigate **more of** the preindustrial European population **than** the 2 or 3 percent who comprised the political and social elite"; specifically, how to comprehend the "more of... than"?

Comment: Think of it as “more than” instead of “more of than.”

Comment: It's "preindustrial", not "prehistoric".

Comment: Traditionally historians only concerned themselves with the actions of "important people" being mostly people with wealth and power. The only "ordinary people" who entered history were those who became famous or infamous in some way. Wat Tyler, George Fox and Michael Faraday are examples. In the 1950s historians began to expand their area of interest to include the lives of "ordinary people". In other words they started to study more members of the population than the small elite they had previously focused on.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have *than*, you have a ***Comparative*** construction. *Than* only occurs in comparatives, and comparatives are very peculiar, complex constructions, containing *more* (or *less* for negatives, or the suffix *-er* for shorter words) as well as an optional baseline comparison introduced with *than*:

- *His list has bigg**er** bullets **than** hers does.*
- *His list is **more** important **than** hers is.*
- *I like her list **better than** his.*
- *There are **more** points on her list **than** on his.*
- ***More** of his list is boldfaced **than** hers.*

Various repeated parts of the baseline comparison constituent (a clause or a phrase) may be deleted and often are, like *hers* standing for *her list*, or *is* standing for *is important*. These two constituents -- the causative constituent and the baseline comparison constituent -- can occur, as one can see, just about anywhere in the sentence, and in many other constructions, though the comparative *more/-er* constituent has to come before the baseline *than* constituent.

The *than* constituent, incidentally, is a negative trigger, generating NPIs like *ever* and *anybody*.

- *He's even faster than **anybody** expected.*
- *He's faster than I **ever** expected.*

Answer (score 0):

*More* here is a fused determiner head - the noun it determines has been left out, and in this case has to be inferred, not taken directly from context. This is because the *than*... part of the comparative construction has *percent* as the term being compared, which is incompatible with *more*:

> *more percent of... than the 2 or 3 percent who comprised...

So we have to interpret it something like:

> a greater percentage of... than the 2 or 3 percent who comprised...

It could be reworded as:

> ...to investigate **a percentage** of the preindustrial European
>   population **greater than** the 2 or 3 percent who comprised the
>   political and social elite...

Comment: why "*more percent of..." is not acceptable ? I think noun can follow "more"

Comment: Given the context, this could also be paraphrased as "more *people* in preindustrial Europe than the 2 or 3 percent...". // Why is "more percent" unacceptable? "Percent is not a noun.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/616793/2085).

Answer (score 0):

More X than Y is a standard construction. It makes a comparison between X and Y.

"to investigate more **[= a greater amount]** of the preindustrial European population than [**=in comparison to**] the 2 or 3 percent (*of that total population*) who comprised the political and social elite";