# What CGEL part of speech is the number in "well over 2000"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, numbers

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 385) has this to say about "cardinal numerals":

> **7.6 Cardinal numerals**  
>  
>  The cardinal numerals are primarily determinatives but they have a secondary use in which they inflect for number and hence belong in the noun category: *They set off in **threes**/enrolled in their **hundreds**.* In practice, only low or round numerals are used in this way. <sup>24</sup> 
>  
> ...
>  
>  <sup>24</sup>Numerals are often used metalinguistically, as the names of symbols: *They added a ‘3’ before all the Brisbane telephone numbers.*

What's the part of speech of the following numbers in CGEL?

> Now, these orbital images tell me that the hostiles' numbers have gone from **a few hundred** to well over **2,000** in one day.
> <Avatar (2009)>

Since they don't inflect for number, they don't seem to belong in the noun category. Nor do they look like determinatives. The only choice left is to say that they are being used metalinguistically, but this doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Fused determiner heads.

Comment: There's an argument that numbers form a distinct grammatical category. Are you specifically interested in what CGEL says or will you accept alternative theories?

Comment: @StuartF I'm primarily interested in CGEL's approach, but other approaches might be necessary if CGEL can't explain what these numbers are.

Comment: You ask a lot of [questions like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fused+determiner+heads). Why did you not like the other answers?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think I've asked "a lot of questions like this". This question is clearly different from my other questions.

Comment: You've asked lots of fused-head questions. I don't know what you're looking for here, so you'd best precisely enumerate for us the allowable set of "parts of speech" you'll accept which people are expected to choose from in answering you. Are you trying to force people to pick one of [Donatus’s storied eight](https://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/donatus.4.html): *nomen, pronomen, verbum, adverbium, participium, coniunctio, praepositio, interiectio*? If those eight ᴀʀᴇ ɴᴏᴛ the exact allowed set without additions or subtractions, you'll need to tell us just which ones you'll permit.

Comment: @tchrist Just because I have previously asked "fused-head questions" doesn't mean those previous questions are the same as or even similar to the current question. And I've clearly asked how CGEL would treat the numbers in question. So hopefully those who are familiar with CGEL would answer it without me having to explain the basics of parts of speech in CGEL.

Comment: This is the kind of issue I have with CGEL: Numerals are often used metalinguistically, as the names of symbols:"They added a ‘3’ before all the Brisbane telephone numbers". Really? The number 3 is a symbol?

Answer (score 2):

In *CGEL* terminology, cardinal numerals—like *2,000* (or *two thousand*) as used in your sentence—are in the lexical category (part of speech)* of ***determinative***.

With the exceptions noted in your quote (and which don’t apply to your sentence), *CGEL* says:

> We will therefore treat all numerals as belonging to the lexical
> category **determinative**, on a par with other unmodified
> determinatives . . . (p. 385)

Your **determinative** appears as part of a determiner in a fused-head noun phrase. Under *Types of determiner* (pp. 355–356), we see:

> . . . **determinatives**
> can . . . combine the function of determiner with
> that of head in the fused-head construction, as in
> [4vi–viii]:
> <sub>. . . [4] vi *He gave ten copies to me and [<sub>–</sub>**six**<sub>–</sub>] to
> the others.* [**simple fused head**] . . .</sub>

In a **simple fused-head** noun phrase, “a head can be added that is recoverable from an antecedent” (p. 333). In your sentence, the recoverable antecedent is not the noun *numbers*, but it might be *hostiles*—as in *two thousand hostiles* (that is, if you don’t mind a possessive antecedent like *hostiles’*; if you do mind, look for a suitable antecedent earlier in the discourse).

To put together *well over two thousand*, see “Minor Determiners PP” (p. 355).

Summary: *2000* is a **determinative**.

---

<sub>*The parts of speech according to *CGEL* are: noun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, determinative, subordinator, coordinator, interjection.</sub>

Comment: In the Avatar example, you say "the recoverable antecedent is not the noun _numbers_, but it might be _hostiles_ —as in _two thousand hostiles_." If that's the case, why can't we replace _2000_ with _2000 hostiles_? *_...the hostiles' numbers have gone from a few hundred **hostiles** to well over 2,000 **hostiles** in one day._ In CGEL's example, on the other hand, you can add _copies_: _He gave ten copies to me and six **copies** to the others._

Comment: You *can* replace *2000* with *2000 hostiles*. *Hostiles* is a noun here, meaning hostile entities. Compare e.g. *2000 natives*, where *natives* stands for native people.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to add _hostiles_ in that sentence, because we're talking about "numbers" not "hostiles". How about this example then? _13 is an unlucky number._ Do you think _13_ here is also a fused-head noun phrase?

Comment: *Numbers* here means “a multitude of people”... Their multitude of people has gone to 2000 people...

Comment: *13*, used “metalinguistically,” is in the noun category.

Comment: Then, how about this example? _Two and three is five._ Here, are the numbers either determinitives or used metalinguistically?

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand your claim that _numbers_ in the Avatar example means “a multitude of people”. In the example, _the hostiles' numbers_ means "the number of hostiles" , not "a great number of hostiles". Strictly speaking, therefore, _number_ should have been singular: _...that the hostiles' **number has** gone from...to..._.

Comment: It means *the numbers of the hostiles* — not *the number of hostiles*. And “a multitude of people” is literally the dictionary definition (*OED*). And looking at the script, your antecedent is *horde*: ”a large unorganized group of individuals.” I think you’re trying to do something like this: *The number is well over a number of 2,000.* But that’s not what’s happening.

Comment: You're referring to the prior sentence: _There's an aboriginal horde out there massing for an attack_, where _an aboriginal horde_ means the same thing as _the hostiles_ in the quoted sentence. But the sentence's subject is not _the hostiles_ but _the hostiles' numbers_. And the use of plural _numbers_ here is unfortunate because he's not talking about two or more numbers. He's talking about a single number that is changing from a few hundred to well over 2,000.

Comment: Fused heads, where *mobile phones* is the recoverable noun: *But the proliferation of mobile phones shows what is possible. Within ten years, their numbers have gone from zero to nearly 1 billion in both India and China.* [1](https://bit.ly/3vjxsd0). Not fused heads, where the noun *nesting turtles* is explicit: *The Hawksbill turtle is one of the seven species of marine turtles and is found in nearshore tropical and subtropical waters of the Atlantic, the Indian, and the Pacific Ocean. Their numbers are believed to be between 20,000 and 23,000 nesting turtles...* [2](https://bit.ly/3RUfBlN)

Comment: In the first example, the plural _numbers_ is used because both the numbers in India and China are being discussed. Similarly, turtles live in different regions, so the plural _numbers_ is used. But in the Avatar example, there is no reason to use the plural _numbers_.

Comment: For idiomatic English best results, please study the word *numbers* as it pertains to multitudes or masses. If you need your numbers to be nouns, try, for example: *The deli counter numbers go from 1 to 99.*

Comment: So are you saying that it'd be wrong to use the singular _number_ in the Avatar example? Also, in _Two and three is five_, are _two_, _three_, and _five_ either determinitives or used metalinguistically?

Comment: It wouldn’t be wrong; it just wouldn’t be what comes naturally when talking about... [**(4) numbers** plural : a numerous group : many](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/number). In *two and three is five*, I suppose those could be nouns or fused-head determiners, depending on the context.

Comment: In M-W's definition (4), its example is: _numbers died on the way_, where _numbers_ cannot be singular. Note in this example that _numbers_ denotes living things because of the predicate is _died on the way_, whereas in the Avatar example, the predicate _have gone from a few hundred to well over 2,000 in one day_ doesn't require the subject to be living things.

Comment: Why can't it be singular? *A number died on the way.* (And we’re not talking about poor noun *2000* perishing.) Your entire argument seems to be based on the premise that *numbers* is being used incorrectly for *number* in your Avatar example. But it’s not.

Comment: But "a number" is an indefinite NP whereas _the hostiles' numbers_ is a definite NP. And the meaning of this NP in the avatar example is not "a number of hostiles" but simply their number itself. You can't say this: *_Now, these orbital images tell me that **a number of hostiles** have gone from a few hundred to well over 2,000 in one day_.

Comment: In your example, *numbers* is correct, and as such, it renders 2000 a fused-head. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

In the example CGEL give to illustrate the nounal usage, few would substitute numerals except perhaps in very informal contexts, say in notemaking. Though 'a few hundred' does not lend itself to numeralisation, the use of 2 000 and the obvious parallel

- ... *the hostiles' numbers have gone from about 300 to well over 2,000 in one day*

argues for non-nounal usage, in spite of the presence of 'numbers'.

On the other hand,

- ... *the hostiles' numbers have gone from the low hundreds to the low thousands in one day*

argues for nounness.

This seems a hybrid usage; 'fused determiner head' seems a reasonable term.

Comment: In your first example, are you saying that 300 and 2,000 are 'fused determiner heads'? If so, what's the common noun that has been fused with 300 and 2,000? _Hostiles_, _numbers_, or something else?

Comment: [Wikipedia describes the usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#:~:text=Determiners%20may%20bear%20two%20functions,that%20functions%20as%20the%20subject.):  << Determiners may bear two functions at one time. Usually this is a fusion of determinative and head in an NP where no head noun exists.  >>

Comment: Your wiki quote is taken from CGEL. And the subsequent sentence in the quote is "In the clause _many would disagree_, the determiner _many_ is the fused determinative-head in the NP that functions as the subject." In this example, _many_ is a fusion of a determiner _many_ and a head noun _people_. Then, in your example what head nouns are the determiners 300 and 2,000 fused with?

Comment: @JK2 Fused determiner-heads don't contain some sort of invisible noun that's been "fused" with the determiner. Instead, the constituent acting as the determiner is also acting as the head of the NP; it's called "fused" because these two functions, normally separate, are being fulfilled by the same element.

Comment: (And while it is true that you can often replace a fused determiner-head with that same determiner + a head noun, that doesn't imply anything about the syntactic structure of the fused determiner-head itself.)

Comment: @alphabet Please give me some examples of Fused determiner-heads that don't contain some sort of invisible noun that's been "fused" with the determiner.

Comment: @JK2 *No* fused determiner-heads work that way.

Comment: Aarts has written an overview of approaches to classifying word usages where the POS is arguable {see ['How can one prove a word is a noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229194/how-can-i-prove-a-word-is-a-noun/229735#229735)}. One is to see a word as a fusion of two POS's. I can't duck this with say 'galore' (quantifier [post-nominal] and adjective [splendid]}.  Another is the gradience model (I prefer this with say 'Brown's deftly **painting** his daughter was a joy to watch'). Another is to say 'It seems 54% noun, 46% verb: it's a noun.' I eschew this.

Comment: @alphabet IF no fused determiner-heads work that way, then you should be able to produce some examples of fused determiner-heads that don't contain some sort of invisible head noun. But apparently, you can't. So, I think you have proved yourself that your statement is not correct.

Comment: @JK2 What do you mean "fused determiner-heads that contain some sort of invisible head noun"? That's a contradiction in terms, since *by definition* fused determiner-head NPs don't contain a head noun outside of the determiner.

Comment: Of interest, perhaps: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46800/is-it-possible-to-have-a-determiner-without-a-complement

Comment: (Let me put it this way: if there were an "invisible head noun" in a fused determiner-head, then the determiner wouldn't be the head, which would mean that it *wasn't* a fused determiner-head.)

Answer (score -2):

> Now, these orbital images tell me that the hostiles' numbers have gone from a few hundred to well over 2,000 in one day. <Avatar (2009)>

This gives us:

Now, these orbital images tell me that the hostiles' numbers have gone from a few hundred **hostiles** (in a day) to well over 2,000 **hostiles** in one day. <Avatar (2009)>

It seems from this that "hostiles" is being used as a common noun derived from the substantive - and not a very natural one. (I have no qualifications in Avatarese.)

Let's take a more orthodox example:

Now, these orbital images tell me that the deaf**'s** numbers have gone from a few hundred *deaf* (in a day) to well over 2,000 *deaf* in one day.

We can parallel this with

Now, these orbital images tell me that the enemy's numbers have gone from a few hundred *enemy* (in a day) to well over 2,000 *enemy* in one day.

If you consider "hundred" to be an adjective - and adjectives are not inflected - then all that has happened is that "deaf people/hostiles" has been omitted a couple of times - as is normal in informal speech.

Comment: The classification of numerals (spelled out or symbols) as adjectives is in many's opinion untenable. There are even good reasons not to class numerals as quantifiers, to which they are much more closely related (both describe the relation of the noun's referent to the environment rather than give inherent details about the referent).